# Using jQuery to change the HTML, but "view source" shows the old one

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I am using  jQuery to dynamically change the loaded html, and while it does work,
when I view the html source of the page in the browser (Chrome) using "View page source" menu, what I see is the old, before changes applied, html code.

Is there a way to see the "after change" html, as at the end of the day, this is what I see in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

View Source will show the initial rendered Html in most cases, Have a look at the DOM model using the development tools.

In Chrome: Ctrl-shift-i

Then look at the Elements tab, the html will change, when manipulated.

Comment: Thank you. But being able to see the changed html code is easier. At least for me. Working with a DOM in that case would seem as an overkill to me - locating a changed node, expanding it to see the child nodes, expanding again ... it would be much  quicker to simple glance at the changed text

Comment: The Elements tab is in fact just the html.

Comment: I see - very useful. It seems to be only showing a top level elements. Is it possible to expand all the elements (and their children, etc) in just one go?

Comment: The Elements tab doesn't show the live DOM, at least not with an angular app, it shows the loaded initial DOM.  Firefox "Show Selection Source" does show the live maniuplated DOM (i.e. after angular processing).

Answer (score 1):

View Source is always going to show you the source as it appeared when the page was sent from the server. In Chrome, you can use Inspect Element (or F12) to bring up the developer console. It has a nice Elements view that will always reflect the current state of the page.

Also, in Firefox you can drag to select part of the page and do "Show Selection Source" and that will be the computed source for that area.